# image processing strategy

Tags: image-processing

I'm planing to build a program which sees the wall, and if it detects objects on wall, it plays specific music.

Because I'm new to Image Processing, I thought and searched some methods.

1. Just capture every frame, and if some kinds of conditions are completed, it conducts actions. (In this case, it plays music.)
2. Save a default image, and keep comparing it with every frame.

I don't know the name of the methods that I described above.

Anyway, I think it is more reasonable to use method 2, because it is less expensive for memory.
Would you give some advice for this problem?
If there is better method to solve this problem, could you give me that method?

Comment: Try Googling `background removal` and `image differencing`. Try telling us what platform/OS you are using? What tools you prefer? How the objects get on the background? Whether this Web-based or desktop?

Comment: Maybe http://programmers.stackexchange.com would be a better place to ask

Comment: @msrd0 Thanks for recommending! I'll also ask in there.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Well, I didn't know that those are important. My OS is Windows 7, IDE is Visual Studio 2012.
Actually, the method the object get on the background is checking  color. If there is red on image, it plays music about red, and so on.
Finally, it will be based on desktop.
Thanks for reminding those things!

Comment: So, imagine I am a user.. how do I put something red on the wall? Drag and drop? Painting?

Comment: @MarkSetchell Ah, I got what you say. Well, I'm planing some kind of Interactive Art. When visitor comes to my work and nails on the wall, it plays the music. the color will be determined neither on the computer or on program, but on real wall. Is the problem that you said clear, right?

Comment: You'll also need a way to remove the person, so you should look into something like Haar cascades to find and remove the user. There are already a lot of pre-trained classifiers out there that should detect humans.